# Error: Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#

Given the **C#** code, shown below, attached to a "**.accdb**" file; when I run it, I receive the message:

> **An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Index (zero based) must be
>   greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument
>   list.**

What's going on?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Hazardous Materials\KinneyDatabase.accdb");

        public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                {
                    vcon.Open();
                }
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Hazardous Materials\cities.txt");
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Hazardous Materials\drugs.txt");
                    string line2 = sr2.ReadLine();

                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                    while (line2 != null)
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(line2);
                        line2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                    }
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = "Date";
                    }
                }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string addRemove = "";

                    if (radioButton1.Checked)
                        {
                            addRemove = radioButton1.Text;
                        }
                    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
                        {
                            addRemove = radioButton2.Text;
                        }
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have entered the following information: \n\n"
                        + " Date: " + textBox2.Text + "\n"
                        + " Store#: " + comboBox1.Text + "\n"
                        + " Medication: " + comboBox2.Text + "\n"
                        + " Quantity: " + textBox1.Text + "\n"
                        + " Initials: " + textBox3.Text + "\n"
                        + " Initials: " + addRemove);

                }

            }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                new Form2().Show();
            }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            Application.Exit();
            }

        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Scripted by Geoff Bertollini. March 2012");
            }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                textBox2.Text = date;
            }

        private void label4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string addRemove = "";

                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    addRemove = radioButton1.Text;
                }
                else if (radioButton2.Checked)
                    {
                        addRemove = radioButton2.Text;
                    }                   

                string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'),comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove");
                OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, vcon);
                vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("The following data has been saved to the database: \n\n"
                        + "Date: " + textBox2.Text + "\n"
                        + "Store#: " + comboBox1.Text + "\n"
                        + "Medication: " + comboBox2.Text + "\n"
                        + "Quantity: " + textBox1.Text + "\n"
                        + "Initials: " + textBox3.Text);
                vcom.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: On which line of your code does the exception occur?

Comment: And a lovely sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

You have a small formatting error **and a giant logic error** in your application.

The giant logic error is that you pass the values from user input directly into an SQL query string; this means that **you are vulnerable to SQL injection**.

This small formatting error is here:

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'),comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove");
```

should instead read:

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove);
```

I moved the double quote from almost the end of the line to a little bit after `{6}`.

The problem was that as written, the whole giant string was being passed as the one and only parameter to `String.Format`, which means that no arguments were available for substitution -- hence the error.

I would suggest that you improve the code formatting, as this kind of error can easily be prevented. Consider formatting like this:

```
string vsql = string.Format(
    "insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",
    comboBox1.Text,
    comboBox2.Text,
    int.Parse(textBox1.Text),
    int.Parse(textBox1.Text),
    textBox2.Text,
    textBox3.Text,
    addRemove);
```

It's so much easier to see what's going on this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you getting, `System.FormatException`, I would look at this line of code:

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'),comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove");
```

It probably should be something like the following (formatted to make it more readable):

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values " + 
    "('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",
    comboBox1.Text, 
    comboBox2.Text, 
    int.Parse(textBox1.Text), 
    int.Parse(textBox1.Text),
    textBox2.Text,
    textBox3.Text,
    addRemove);
```

What you had originally didn't supply any elements to the format array as they were part of the string itself (which likely isn't what you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'),comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove");
```

That needs to be this:

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values ({0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, addRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with [C# 6 string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is available that eliminates the need to count through the arguments.

You new call could look like this:

```
string vsql = $"insert into Log values ('{comboBox1.Text}','{comboBox2.Text}','{int.Parse(textBox1.Text)}','{int.Parse(textBox1.Text)}','{textBox2.Text}','{textBox3.Text}','{addRemove}')";
```